# PHP reading external xml file - encoding issue

Tags: php, xml, readxml

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1254">
</head>
<body>
    <?php
    $url = 'http://www.koeri.boun.edu.tr/sismo/zeqmap/xmlt/son24saat.xml';
    $html = file_get_contents($url);

//Change encoding to UTF-8 from ISO-8859-1
    $a = iconv('ISO-8859-1', 'UTF-8//IGNORE', $html);

    print_r($a);

    ?>

</body>
```

> ÿþ<�?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?> <�eqlist> ...

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: your converting to UTF-8, yet telling the browser to use windows-1254

Comment: fixed it but it did not

Answer (score 0):

Your charset is not utf-8 but the xml encoding is.